# how do I save a html/css edit to chrome so it always displays a site with the edits?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

For example, I'm trying to hide a determinate element of a webpage by deleting it in the "elements" section of F12 inspection, and I want chrome to always consider that edit (so that whenever I open that webpage the element is hidden). hope I explained well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect a folder via Filesystem tab on Sources.
[image]
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/